# Why does setInterval() ignore errors?

Tags: javascript, function, exception, setinterval

Javascript's [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) seems to pay no attention to whether or not the code it calls throws exceptions. For instance, this will not terminate the program but call the function over and over again:

```
setInterval(function() { throw "error" }, 1000);
```

What is the reason for this behaviour? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: "will not terminate the program" --- how do you see that? As the whole browser tab crash?

Comment: What could possibly handle the exception sanely?

Comment: Async callbacks and try...catch don't mix.

Comment: @zerkms: I see that the Javascript code continues to run as if nothing had happened, and there's no exception handling in my code.

Comment: @eugene y: yes, it continues. But how do you see the "terminate the program" in context of JS? Should the whole tab/browser die?

Comment: @zerkms I think he means that the `setInterval` should terminate.

Comment: @Vivin Paliath: `setInterval` callback does terminate.

Comment: @zerkms No, it doesn't. At least not in chrome. When I have the following code: `setInterval(function() { throw e;}, 1000);` I get exceptions thrown every second. The interval does not terminate.

Comment: @Vivin Paliath: well, a particular callback execution does terminate. Not sure why the whole iterative process should. `setInterval` just schedules a function invocation.

Comment: @zerkms I was just clarifying what I thought the OP was asking.

Comment: @Vivin Paliath: OP asked about "terminating the program". For me "the program" in context of (browser) JS is the whole runtime, not a particular call.

Comment: The next interval is put into a queue and will be executed when its time, that's how the event loop model works in JavaScript. This happens with anything asynchronous in nature, like setInterval. You may want to use setTimeout, that way you have control over when to stop calling it. Or you could stop the interval after throwing the error.

Comment: @zerkms I was trying to hazard a guess as to what the OP meant. I have no idea what he actually means. Terminating the entire runtime doesn't make any sense to me either. I figured that he might have been talking about the iterative execution.

Comment: @zerkms: If you call `throw` outside of a `try` block, your Javascript program usually terminates at this point, doesn't it? That's what I expected from `setInterval` also.

Comment: defining a function that throws doesn't actually throw though.

Comment: @eugene y: "your Javascript program usually terminates at this point, doesn't it" --- nope, it doesn't

Comment: @zerkms: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw

Comment: @eugene y: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/2m58hnug/ There is misunderstanding of the "program" term. The whole event loop is not terminated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MDN docs for [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) say, for a thrown object:

> If no catch block exists among caller functions, the program will terminate.

This isn't strictly accurate. [ECMAScript spec section 10.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4)

> A thrown exception may also exit one or more execution contexts.

This is more accurate.

What is an execution context? Well, there's one for your original program. When you make a function call, a nested context is created while that function is running. A call to `eval` will make one. 10.4 covers this.

In general, when an exception is thrown, it will pass up through all of the nested execution contexts until it is caught, or it reaches the outer execution context. If it is not caught within an execution context, that context will be terminated. Thus, if your original program is the outermost execution context, it will terminate on an uncaught exception?

When your handler function is called, due to your `setTimeout` interval expiring, **it** is the outermost execution context. Thus, the uncaught exception terminates it, but it is not nested within your original program. So nothing else gets terminated.

The thread that's handling the timer expires is part of the JS engine, so you're not going to terminate that either. Thus, once per interval, a new execution context is created when your handler function is called and so it repeats.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the function to be called over and over again, catch the exception and clear the timer. This example counts down from five, printing to the console, and throws an exception when the value is less than zero:

```
var counter = 5;
var timer;

var decrement = function() {
    try {
        if ( counter < 0 ) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            throw new Error("Invalid count");
        }
        console.log(counter);
        counter -= 1;
    }
    catch ( error ) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

timer = setInterval(decrement, 1000);
```

It is up to you to decide if the function should or should not be called again. An exception stops execution of the function but there is no "program" to terminate. The web browser is the "program". If it runs a function that throws an exception, it still continues to service other events. That is the expected behavior.

Why doesn't it cancel the timer on an exception? You may want that when trying to load a resource that may fail and clear the timer on success.

Comment: I would suggest that it would have been helpful to have `setInterval` take a parameter indicating whether a thrown exception from one execution should cancel all subsequent ones; there are usage cases where such cancellation would be appropriate and others where it would not.  The existence of cases where it's best not to have an error on one timer event cancel all repeated events means that the design where thrown exceptions don't kill timers is reasonable, even though providing additional choices would have been helpful.

Comment: Upon further consideration, I figured out a good reason why JS doesn't do that: because cancelling a timer makes its id available for reuse, it's important that every timer which may need to be "manually" cancelled have its ID be stored in exactly one place, and that any action which would cancel the timer invalidate the stored ID.  If a timer were canceled without invalidating the stored ID, code which later wanted to cancel the timer (without realizing it was already dead) might instead end up cancelling some other arbitrary timer.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setInterval`, the runtime doesn't know if the callback will throw.

```
var shouldThrow = false;
setInterval(function () {
    if (shouldThrow) throw 'error';
    console.log('program has not stopped');
}, 5000);

// nothing is wrong at this point.
// thus, the program continues
shouldThrow = confirm('Throw error?');
```

You'll find that if the callback throws, it *does* terminate "the program," that being the callback itself. In this example, if you click the OK button, the callback will not proceed to the `console.log` call. It does continue to call the callback repeatedly though. If you later change `shouldThrow` again, you'll see more messages in the console.